# Java GUI MasterMind

Tags: java

I am going to make a game in Java which is Number Mastermind.

Now the AI generates 4 numbers from 1-6 and then the user has to guess it.

Now I've got 20 mins of GUI interface and I'm struggling on how to best approach this and the use of the layouts.

But my question is this:

If a random number is 1122 how do I compare it to a guess and output values according to the users input.

For example 1122 and the user guesses 1133 how can I output RRWW r means correct number and location and W means wrong?

Not been doing java too long so kinda new to me.

Comment: You really should do some reseach on your own.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What bit do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `int` to a String, then to a `char[]` and compare each of the values and put them into a `boolean[]` array which tells whether they got it right or wrong E.g:

```
boolean[] howManyRight(int number, int guess, int length){
    char[] n = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
    char[] g = String.valueOf(guess).toCharArray();
    boolean[] rightAnswers = new boolean[length];        

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        boolean[i] = n[i] == g[i];
    }

    return rightAnswers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how familiar you are with Mastermind, but typically the result for your example would just be RR.  Completely incorrect numbers technically don't need to be discussed. Instead, W could represent numbers that are in the code, but in the wrong place. So if we change your example slightly (Generated code can still be 1122, but guess from user is now 1234), it would generate a result of R W. (1 right, and 1 in the wrong spot) To achieve this looks something like this:

```
public String compareGuessToCode(String guess,String code) {
    //Variable to store result to show the user
    String result = "";
    //Necessary variables for code comparison
    //These xxxCharCount variables are used to keep track of how many of each possible
    // character are used in the guess and the code.
    int[] guessCharCount = new int[6];
    int[] codeCharCount  = new int[6];
    //These variables are used for bookkeeping during the evaluation process
    int   guessCharVal   = 0;
    int   guessValPos    = 0;
    int   codeCharVal    = 0;
    int   codeValPos     = 0;
    //Variables to keep track of perfectly correct and wrong position characters
    int   r              = 0;
    int   w              = 0;
    //Set all positions in xxxCharCount to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        guessCharCount[i] = 0;
        codeCharCount[i]  = 0;
    }
    //Analyze the code
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
        codeCharVal = (int) code.charAt(i);
        codeValPos  = codeCharVal - 1;
        codeCharCount[codeValPos] += 1;
    }
    //Analyze the guess
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
        guessCharVal = (int) guess.charAt(i);
        guessValPos  = guessCharVal - 1;
        //Compare guess characters to code characters
        if (guess.charAt(i) == code.charAt(i)) {
            //Show the position as correct
            r++;
            //Increment the appropriate slot in the character counter
            guessCharCount[guessValPos]++;
        }
    }
    //We want to check if the any guess characters are in the code, but we also want
    //to ensure that we haven't already accounted for all occurrences of the
    //guessed character in the code.
    for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
        guessCharVal = (int) guess.charAt(i);
        if (code.contains(String.valueOf(guess.charAt(i))) && guessCharCount[guessValPos] < codeCharCount[guessValPos]) {
            //Show the character as present, but in the wrong spot
            w++;
            //Increment the appropriate slot in the character counter
            guessCharCount[guessValPos]++;
        }
    }
    //Build the result string...perfect first...
    for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result += "P";
        } else {
            result += " P";
        }
    }
    //...wrong spot last
    for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++) {
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result += "X";
        } else {
            result += " X";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```